# Does numbers need to be strings to avoid precision errors?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm trying to make an eth dapp and I am using react to create the front end. This error came from the front end side. This is my error I got 2 of them both saying the same thing error:

> Please pass numbers as strings or BN objects to avoid precision errors

I tried putting toString() at the end of tokenBalance and ethBalance but I just got error:

> Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined

Here is my code:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import tokenLogo from '../token-logo.png'
import ethLogo from '../eth-logo.png'


class Main extends Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
          output: '0'
        }
      }

    render(){
        return (
            <div id="content">
                <div className="card mb-4" >

<div className="card-body">

<form className="mb-3" onSubmit={(event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    let etherAmount
    etherAmount = this.input.value.toString()
    etherAmount = window.web3.utils.toWei(etherAmount, 'Ether')
    this.props.buyTokens(etherAmount)
  }}>
  <div>
    <label className="float-left"><b>Input</b></label>
    <span className="float-right text-muted">
      Balance: {window.web3.utils.fromWei(this.props.ethBalance.toString(), 'Ether')}
    </span>
  </div>
  <div className="input-group mb-4">
    <input
      type="text"
      onChange={(event) => {
        const etherAmount = this.input.value.toString()
        this.setState({
          output: etherAmount * 100
        })
      }}
      ref={(input) => { this.input = input }}
      className="form-control form-control-lg"
      placeholder="0"
      required />
    <div className="input-group-append">
      <div className="input-group-text">
        <img src={ethLogo} height='32' alt=""/>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; ETH
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label className="float-left"><b>Output</b></label>
    <span className="float-right text-muted">
      Balance: {window.web3.utils.fromWei(this.props.tokenBalance, 'Ether')}
    </span>
  </div>
  <div className="input-group mb-2">
    <input
      type="text"
      className="form-control form-control-lg"
      placeholder="0"
      value={this.state.output}
      disabled
    />
    <div className="input-group-append">
      <div className="input-group-text">
        <img src={tokenLogo} height='32' alt=""/>
        &nbsp; DApp
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div className="mb-5">
    <span className="float-left text-muted">Exchange Rate</span>
    <span className="float-right text-muted">1 ETH = 100 DApp</span>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-lg">SWAP!</button>
</form>

</div>

</div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Main;
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to test that your prop has a value before you try to use the `toString` method on it. Something like:

```
<span className="float-right text-muted">
  Balance: {this.props.ethBalance ? window.web3.utils.fromWei(this.props.ethBalance.toString(), 'Ether') : ''}
</span>
```